# SSAS Driver error when refreshing the cube

Tags: excel, ssas, driver, olap

One of my users can connect to the cube okay, however once she tries to refresh the data in excel she gets an error

I can connect to the cube and refresh ok. I have sent my template over to the user to try and use but no luck

Here is the error message that comes up:

> An operation that uses the database driver could not be completed. If
>   the driver is a Microsoft driver, make sure the driver file isnt
>   damaged, and if it is, reinstall the driver by reinstalling Microsoft
>   Query. For other drivers, contact your database administrator or
>   driver vendor.

I don't think reinstalling Microsoft Query would do the trick as I can connect and refresh the cube without issues